# Can I perform magnitude analysis on margins?

Tags: econometrics, applied-econometrics

I’m trying to find if there’s an asymmetric in my dummy variables. So after creating my regression I am looking at margins with all the variables held constant with the dummy=1,0.5 ( a pseudo result I am making for a benchmark),0. I am then multiplying the margins by the standard errors so that they are in the same scale. By taking the differences of the dummy=0 from the dummy=0.5 and dummy=0.5 from dummy=1. This should show asymmetric magnitudes.

Relating this back to my question can. Can I do magnitude analysis in this manor?